# Hide/Show <div> using javascript and select

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please help me fix this problem.

I have the following html:

```
<form>    
  <select class="form-control" id="order_bid_ord_type">
    <option value="market">market</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="limit">limit</option>
  </select>
  <div id="bid_mo_container">
     Hello world   
  </div>
</form>
```

I have the following javascript

```
$('#order_bid_ord_type').on('change', function() {
  if (this.value === 'market') {
    $('#bid_mo_container').show();
  } else if (this.value === 'limit') {
    $('#bid_mo_container').hide();
  }
});
```

And the following CSS:

```
#order_bid_ord_type{
  display: none;
}
```

My JS Fiddle is here

http://jsfiddle.net/D46Zb/59/

And here is what I want to do: **When I select market from the combo box, I want the hello world text to show. And when I select limit, I want it to disappear**

Right now, nothing happens when I change my selection. Can you help me figure out where the problem with my code is?

Comment: The code in your fiddle doesn't match the code in your question, plus you forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle. Fix that and it works http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gLymeed9/

Comment: Yep... remember to include jQuery.  Also, some of the code can be written a little more compactly: http://jsfiddle.net/z1bc7pgx/1

Answer (score 1):

There are no error in your code.You forgot to include jquery.

Below is working fiddle.

```js
$('#order_bid_ord_type').on('change', function() {
  if (this.value === 'market') {
    $('#bid_mo_container').show();
  } else if (this.value === 'limit') {
    $('#bid_mo_container').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#bid_mo_container
{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
<form>    
  <select class="form-control" id="order_bid_ord_type">
    <option value="market">market</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="limit">limit</option>
  </select>
  <div id="bid_mo_container">
     Hello world   
  </div>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Kroonal/ybw8Lv06/

Answer (score 0):

I'd change

```
this.value === 'market'
```

to

```
$(this).val() == 'market'
```

Same with the other option in your JS

Comment: What?... but why?  There's no reason to use a method rather than reference the native property and there's no reason to allow for type casting in this case (`==` vs `===`)

Comment: Can anybody answer this? I'm also curious....My guess is that your using a JQuery wrapper method to listen to the change event.

Comment: If you go to jQuery  always use jQuery. Main purpose of this is to use the wrapper functions of it to achieve browser compatibility.